# Finding a factor of 600851475143 that lies between 2 and 100

Tags: php

I wrote a script to find a factors of 600851475143 that lies between 2 and 100. However I get different values when I ran the script on my local machine and when I ran it on Phpfiddle.org On Phpfiddle I get the correct answer of 71 but on my machine the script simple returns 100 which is wrong. What could be causing this? The code is below

```
<?php

$n = 600851475143;

for ($i=2; $i < 100; $i++) { 

 $result = ($n/$i);

 if (is_int($result)) {

     break;
     return $i;
 }
 }
echo $i;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP Manual: Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> The division operator ("/") returns a float value unless the two operands are integers (or strings that get converted to integers) and the numbers are evenly divisible, in which case an integer value will be returned.

---

Your local machine is using 32-bit integers, the largest of which is 2147483647. Either you've got a 32-bit build or you're on Windows using a PHP version prior to 7.

Because 600851475143 is larger than your maximum integer it is converted to a float, and your division will therefore always return a float as well.

If you

```
var_dump(600851475143/71)
```

on your local system you'll get

```
float(8462696833)
```

while any system using 64-bit integers will give you

```
int(8462696833)
```

as 600851475143 and 71 are well within 64-bit bounds.

---

A method that works across both 32 and 64-bit systems is to check if there is remainder of division using [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php), e.g.:

```
$n = 600851475143;

for ($i=2; $i < 100; $i++) {
    if (!fmod($n, $i)) {
        break;
    }
}

echo $i;
```

Will give you `71` regardless of integer size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result of your division is always a `float` so your condition will never match.

A possible solution would be to cast it to a string and check if all characters are digits:

```
if (ctype_digit((string) $result)) {
```

That would result in `71`, see [an example](https://eval.in/646129).

Comment: Thanks, I get 71 as expected on my local machine. However when I tried your code on Phpfiddle.org I get 2

Comment: @CalebOki Looks like they are seriously rounding the output :-)